# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, linker

I am getting the following linking error in Xcode 6. Any ideas how to solve this

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SCClip._m4g1c in:
    /Users/Abdul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SoundCandy-bwekfiwyyjgmwhbgztfrqedobxxn/Build/Intermediates/SoundCandy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SoundCandyTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SCClip-F338C753334EE43A.o
duplicate symbol _SCCLIP_INPUT_TOKEN in:
    /Users/Abdul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SoundCandy-bwekfiwyyjgmwhbgztfrqedobxxn/Build/Intermediates/SoundCandy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SoundCandyTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SCClip-F338C753334EE43A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SCClip in:
    /Users/Abdul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SoundCandy-bwekfiwyyjgmwhbgztfrqedobxxn/Build/Intermediates/SoundCandy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SoundCandyTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SCClip-F338C753334EE43A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SCClip in:
    /Users/Abdul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SoundCandy-bwekfiwyyjgmwhbgztfrqedobxxn/Build/Intermediates/SoundCandy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SoundCandyTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SCClip-F338C753334EE43A.o
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by selecting and deselecting target membership of the problematic file in the file inspector in `Xcode`